# Is the name of the angel Mekaal or Mekaa'il?

Tags: quran, malaikah

What is the correct Arabic name of the angel? Is it Mekaal (ميكال) or Mekaa'il (ميكائيل)?

The Quran (2:98) refers to the angel as Mekaal, but I have heard most people refer to him as Mekaa'il.

http://quran.com/2/98

```
مَن كَانَ عَدُوًّا لِّلَّهِ وَمَلَائِكَتِهِ وَرُسُلِهِ وَجِبْرِيلَ وَمِيكَالَ فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ عَدُوٌّ لِّلْكَافِرِينَ
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_%28archangel%29) refers to him as Mekaa'il.

Answer (score 3):

The name is one, whether "ميكال" or "ميكائيل", But the difference in pronunciation and dialect ..

For detailed answer to a question, must first search about Ten novels and seven readings of Quran.

It is the differences in pronunciation and dialect only (by Arab tribes in antiquity)
the previous verse came "ميكال" in [Hafs from Asim novels "رواية حفص عن عاصم"](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%AD%D9%81%D8%B5_%D8%B9%D9%86_%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%85),and Came "ميكائيل" in shoba from Asim novel "رواية شعبة عن عاصم"

[this wikipedia page](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86) about Quran's novels (but only in arabic)

**A brief summary of the difference between the novels of Quran:**

- each verse in the Quran has several readings and novels connected with the Prophet, peace be upon him may be,the difference between them include specific words, or pronunciation depending on the rules of each reading, as well as verse drawing may different from one reading to another.
- The differences between these readings is not known except the Special experienced in readings Sciences who received this science by sheikhs and Quran's readers,and studied the Quran by scholars from generation to generation access to the Prophet, peace be upon him may be.
- And most of the novels Quran widespread today in most Arab and Islamic countries is [Hafs from Asim "حفص عن عاصم"](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%AD%D9%81%D8%B5_%D8%B9%D9%86_%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%85)

Comment: I'd like to add: The spelling Mika'il ميكائيل is approved by the quraa' Nafi', ibn Kathir, ibn 'Amir, Hamzah, al-Kissaa-i , Abu Ja'afar and Khalaf and it is also the riwaya of Shoaba 'an 'Asim. So the exception of this is ميكال which is only the riwaya of Hafs 'an 'Asim and of the both Basri quraa' Ya'qub and abu 'Amr among the 10 approved readings.

Answer (score 0):

they are the same ! I see that both names are used in quran and suna .

---

**edit:**

from suna the prophet mohamed peace be upon him said :

> قال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم:
>   ما لي لا أرى **ميكائيل** ضاحكا قط ؟ قال : ما ضحك ميكائيل منذ خلقت النار

so he used Mekaa'il .

from quran : allh named the angle Mekaal as the question state that very clear .

Comment: Any resources you want to refer?

Comment: @Adil Soomro I added the evidence from suna .